# friction in pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction

Suppose there is a a pulley with which two masses are attached.Assume the strings to be light and inextensible.If friction is present between string and the  pulley ie the pulley is not smooth  then will the mechanical energy be conserved for this system?

Comment: -1 Not clear. What do you mean by *friction is present across the pulley*? Do you mean friction between the string and the pulley, or friction in the axle of the pulley?

Comment: I think he meant friction in the axle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Energy is conserved regardless of friction.

If friction is present, then a part of the total energy is used up in overcoming friction, and appears as heat.

However, *mechanical* energy is conserved only if friction is *absent*. The energy lost in overcoming friction appears as heat and cannot be accounted for as mechanical energy.

Comment: what will friction between pulley do that will rresult in generation of heat

Comment: It will actually not do anything. Friction opposes motion. So, an amount of energy has to be used up to overcome friction. This used up energy becomes useless, and appears as heat in the pulley.

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla Your question remains unclear. You should edit your question to clarify the issue sammy gerbil pointed out.

Comment: @WrichikBasu will the string become hot due to this heat

Comment: If there is static friction between the pulley and string, and no friction  in the pulley axle, mechanical energy will remain constant, but some of the kinetic energy will belong to the rotation of the pulley. If there is zero friction between the pulley and string, mechanical energy will remain constant.

Comment: @harambe it may, it may not. If the string is a thread, it will get very slightly hot as it's a bad conductor of heat. A steel wire, on the other hand, will show greater temperature. The pulley will heat up. The rest depends on thermal conductivity of the wire.